# Javascript throws 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, requirejs, jsonata

I am running a piece of Javascript code inside my Python code using the `js2py` library.It works fine for all kinds of Javascript code thrown at it and processes the result.However I am encountering an error when a **'require'** keyword is used in the Javascript code.Here is my code below

```
import js2py

data = '''var jsonata = require('jsonata');

var data = {
  example: [
    {value: 4},
    {value: 7},
    {value: 13}
  ]
};
var expression = jsonata("$sum(example.value)");
var result = expression.evaluate(data);
console.log(result);
'''

data = js2py.eval_js(data)
print(data)
```

Here **jsonata** is a javascript library for parsing JSON installed through npm.

Below is the error I receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/PycharmProjects/ServiceHandler/Testjs.py", line 67, in <module>
    data = js2py.eval_js(data)
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 113, in eval_js
    return e.eval(js)
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 182, in eval
    self.execute(code, use_compilation_plan=use_compilation_plan)
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 177, in execute
    exec(compiled, self._context)
  File "<EvalJS snippet>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/base.py", line 899, in __call__
    return self.call(self.GlobalObject, args)
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/base.py", line 1344, in call
    return Js(self.code(*args))
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/host/jseval.py", line 42, in Eval
    executor(py_code)
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/host/jseval.py", line 49, in executor
    exec(code, globals())
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/js2py/base.py", line 1079, in get
    raise MakeError('ReferenceError', '%s is not defined' % prop)
js2py.internals.simplex.JsException: ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

However when I put just the javascript code in a file and run it from the command line, it works.

**jstest.js**

```
var jsonata = require("jsonata");

var data = {
  example: [
    {value: 4},
    {value: 7},
    {value: 13}
  ]
};
var expression = jsonata("$sum(example.value)");
var result = expression.evaluate(data); 
console.log(result)
```

In the command line

```
node jstest.js  --> gives 25
```

Now I did some investigation on the error and it turns out that **'require'** is a browser requirement and is not for `node.js`. It also turns out there is an alternative for this called `require.js` that fixes this problem.So I went to their documentation but couldn't make much sense of how I could define **require** in my Javascript code.Also I pass jsonata as an argument to **require** which is a **.js** file.How do I use `require.js` framework to handle a jsonata.js file as opposed to function declaration given in the examples?I may be wrong in my understanding of the subject but I need to get a clarification on this?Is there any way I can make this work?

Note: I am running the code in the server side.

Comment: @Archer Yes, this link `https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/blob/master/README.md` has the Javascript code that I need to run.

Comment: `require` in this context is a Node keyword to import node modules. It might take more work than simply use `require.js` to load it in the browser, maybe try with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) instead?

Comment: @Kaddath Oh by the way I am running this code in the server side so loading anything in the browser doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, but you need to make the javascript runnable by your python eval, wich was the point of it

Comment: @Kaddath sorry but I don't quite understand.Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See Alekhya Satya's answer which is most probably what you need. The thing is that the Javascript you want to run must be supported by your `js2py.eval_js` function. I assumed it couldn't understand Node's `require` because it's not a standard Javascript function, it's specific to Node. But as Alekhya Satya states, it is understood by the new version

Answer (score 2):

Please  try the newest Js2Py that supports requiring npm modules.The issue with your code was just that require was not supported.Please add this statement after importing js2py.

```
from js2py import require
```

Please let me know if your code is working fine after the new addition.

Comment: Hey I need to define the javascript code inside a string.So it has nothing to do with what I import.This piece of javascript code is independent.

Comment: Please see this example  [link]https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py/blob/master/examples/importing_node_module.py     ,you need to import require module before using the same.

Comment: Yes I understand that the code you have placed in quotes and given to js2py.eval_js() will be interpreted as javascript code and the outer python code has nothing to do with it,but we are not sure how js2py.eval_js() is implemented,it might or might not add the npm modules used in JS code,hence add it .

Comment: hey I added it.So it installs the jsonata as an independent javascript library but it doesn't influence the code inside the string and continues to throw the error.

Comment: require is not defined in js2py.eval_js,hence require is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons the `require` is not supported by default in JS context. You can easily enable it though:

```py
>>> context = js2py.EvalJs(enable_require=True)
>>> context.eval("require('esprima').parse('var a = 1')")
```

As Alekhya Satya mentioned in his answer you can also import `require` directly and use it from the python context.